# Rails rspec testing a user sending a message to himself/herself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to test so a user cannot send a message to himself.  Currently on my new message view, I have a select box which gives a selection of all the users in the system except for the current_user.  Currently I only have a test which does not allow a user to select himself as the recipient from the select box:

```
it { should_not have_select(:receiver_id, :options => [user.name]) }
```

However, is this enough of a test?  Do I need to test creating a new message, setting the :receiver_id to the current_user's id and check for it?  If so, where would I put this spec, in the model or a request?

**Edit (added a validation method in the Message Model, but my rspec passes even if I comment out the validate line):**

**Edit 2 (The test for the errors hash does not pass):**

Message.rb:

```
validate :validate_sender_receiver

def validate_sender_receiver
    if self.receiver_id == self.sender_id
        errors.add(:receiver_id, "Cannot send message to self")
    end
end
```

messages_spec.rb

```
describe "sending message to yourself" do
    before do
        @message = user.sent_messages.new(:receiver_id => user.id)
    end

    it "should not be valid" do
        @message.should_not be_valid
    end

    it "should set the error hash" do
        @message.errors.should include("Cannot send message to self")
    end


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed:

```
it "should set the error hash" do
    @message.errors.should include("Cannot send message to self")
end
```

to:

```
it "should set the error hash" do
    @message.errors.should have_key(:receiver_id)
end
```

And it now works out well, still don't understand why the first method doesn't work?  Does the have_key just check to see if there is a key, but not if it's empty?

Answer (score 1):

If a user hacks your select and adds himself to the possible values you might end up with a message that you don't want. I don't know what your controller's action looks like but you should test that in the model and your model should reject the message if the receiver is the same as the sender.

Comment: I made the changes above, but I'm not sure if I did it right?